# Entity framework - best way to access dblayer in a wcf service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I am using Entity Framework for my WCF service.
At the moment I am referring DBlayer from all other layers of service. Dblayer has a model and associated(nested) dbcontext and entity classes that were created by default under EDMX file when created a Model using VS2012.

Until now, if any table design changes were made in sql server, my development effort is less because I am just updating model that recreates/refresh my entity classes.

Now, I want to avoid referring my model from everywhere. Would you please guide me for a best way to refer dblayer and how to maintain entity classes and dbcontext. If separate entity classes into different assembly, how do they get refresh if any table design changes.

or is it fine to continue referring model(DBLayer) from all layers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Repository pattern [EF and Repository](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/561584/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-using)

and [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

the Repository allows you do not depend on persistance but you model object enities if they satisfy your business objects it is ok that you reference on they in al layers take a look on [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

Comment: Thank you, I am going to through the links. I might continue referring dblayer from entire service as my model obj entities and business objects are almost similar.

Comment: you should keep you model classes in domain not ib dbLayer, in this layer you will keep persitanse classes such as Repositories implementations.